# Getting pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError when attempting to connect to a CosmosDB database

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm getting a Getting pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError when attempting to connect to a CosmosDB database from my local computer.

```
uri = "uri given by the CosmosDB console"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client.test
collection = db.test
collection.insert_one({"field1": "foo", "field2": "bar"})
```

On the last statement it throws: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed

I've also tried adding the ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE parameter which some blog posts recommended, but it still threw the same error. I'm using pymongo 3.10.1

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured this out. I needed to add my ip address to the firewall to allow it through. Then I got an AutoReconnect error and needed to add retrywrites=false to the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue earlier, you could add `?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE` after the database name in the string you are passing to MongoClient  , which would look like,

```
db_name = os.getenv("MONGO_DB")
host = os.getenv("MONGO_HOST")
port = 10255
username = os.getenv("MONGO_USERNAME")
password = os.getenv("MONGO_PASSWORD")
args = "ssl=true&retrywrites=false&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE"

connection_uri = f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}?{args}"
```

Comment: I tried that, but the uri I get from the CosmosDB console is a bit different than yours. Looks like this. uri = "mongodb://{user}:{pass}@{url}:{port}/?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&replicaSet=globaldb&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName={appname}"